Need to restart twice to boot into ubuntu
So I'm dual booting Ubuntu and windows( both are in the same drive sharing the same ESP partition of 100 MiB ). The root partition is in the same drive as of windows and the home partition is in my other disk( HDD ) for storage. However, what's wrong is that whenever I startup my machine, i boot into grub command line, for a split second however, before i can see the command line mode of grub, at the top right corner I can see the text: error: command failed being repeated multiple times. Now after seeing the command line mode, i have two options:
type exit and it would then just boot into windows automatically.
OR
type reboot and then, I can see the grub menu and everything then works as expected.
This is somewhat related to my past experience with Ubuntu where the menu is shown but whenever I used to click on an entry in the grub menu, it would just say error: command failed ( this line was repeated like 3-4 times ) and then it would say press any key to continue, when I do that it would just return to the grub menu. I had to then go to the command line mode and reboot multiple times to get to any operating system.
